# Add two media sources in topology and display mix video - Windows Media Foundation

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I am exploring windows media foundation.
I want to mix and display two video stream in one window.
I am following few of the sample provided by MS.

I am trying to Add multiple media sources to topology, I want to add two media files to topology.

As per the below link, I am following code to add media source in topology:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701605(v=vs.85).aspx

Below is the code to add source node to the topology:

```
HRESULT hr = pPD->GetStreamDescriptorByIndex(iStream, &fSelected, &pSD);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    goto done;
}

if (fSelected)
{
    // Create the media sink activation object.
    hr = CreateMediaSinkActivate(pSD, hVideoWnd, &pSinkActivate);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Add a source node for this stream.
    hr = AddSourceNode(pTopology, pSource, pPD, pSD, &pSourceNode);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Create the output node for the renderer.
    hr = AddOutputNode(pTopology, pSinkActivate, 0, &pOutputNode);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Connect the source node to the output node.
    hr = pSourceNode->ConnectOutput(0, pOutputNode, 0);
}
```

But I am not able to add multiple media source in my topology.
My single file playback is working properly but I am not able to mix and display two files.

Comment: How do you add the sources actually? Do you use source resolver, aggregate source or sequencer source?

Comment: @VuVirt: I am using source aggregator to create one source from multiple video source. But now struggling with displaying two video in one renderer using EVR and display control.

Comment: I'm not sure that the standard IMFMediaSession supports multiple video inputs for EVR. You might need to implement a custom Media Session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend split your task on five step:
1. write code for playing ONE video file. On MSDN there is example code: [How to Play Media Files with Media Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703190(v=vs.85).aspx).
2. research code of WORKABLE player for point, where created MediaSource from video file path(URL).
3. create TWO MediaSource from two video file paths(URL).
4. by function [MFCreateAggregateSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388085(v=vs.85).aspx) create from TWO MediaSource - ONE MediaSource and retuurn MediaSource from method player `HRESULT CreateMediaSource(PCWSTR sURL, IMFMediaSource **ppSource)`
5. call 'hr = AddOutputNode(pTopology, pSinkActivate, 0, &pOutputNode);' twice: 'hr = AddOutputNode(pTopology, pSinkActivate, 0, &pOutputNode);' for first video stream and `hr = AddOutputNode(pTopology, pSinkActivate, 1, &pOutputNode);` for second video stream.

Regards.

P.S. If you will use two video with audio streams, then You will have FOUR streams in Aggregate MediaSource - it could need FIND the stream ID for video stream.
P.S.S It is not easy recommend from viewing only demo code, but in `CreateMediaSinkActivate` you will find code `hr = MFCreateVideoRendererActivate(hVideoWindow, &pActivate);`. In your code, you must create this `Activate` before:

```
// For each stream, create the topology nodes and add them to the topology.
for (DWORD i = 0; i < cSourceStreams; i++)
{
    hr = AddBranchToPartialTopology(pTopology, pSource, pPD, i, hVideoWnd);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }
}
```

then set this crated `Activate` as argument for `AddBranchToPartialTopology`

for example:

```
hr = MFCreateVideoRendererActivate(hVideoWindow, &pVideoRendererActivate);
// For each stream, create the topology nodes and add them to the topology.
for (DWORD i = 0; i < cSourceStreams; i++)
{
    hr = AddBranchToPartialTopology(pTopology, pSource, pPD, i, pVideoRendererActivate);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }
}
```

In `AddBranchToPartialTopology`you must write something like this:

```
HRESULT AddBranchToPartialTopology(
IMFTopology *pTopology,         // Topology.
IMFMediaSource *pSource,        // Media source.
IMFPresentationDescriptor *pPD, // Presentation descriptor.
DWORD iStream,                  // Stream index.
IMFActivate* aVideoRendererActivate)                 // VideoRenderer for video playback.
{
IMFStreamDescriptor *pSD = NULL;
IMFActivate         *pSinkActivate = NULL;
IMFTopologyNode     *pSourceNode = NULL;
IMFTopologyNode     *pOutputNode = NULL;

BOOL fSelected = FALSE;

HRESULT hr = pPD->GetStreamDescriptorByIndex(iStream, &fSelected, &pSD);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    goto done;
}

DWORD iStreamID = 0;

if (fSelected)
{
    // Create the media sink activation object.
    hr = CreateMediaSinkActivate(pSD, iStreamID, aVideoRendererActivate, &pSinkActivate);
```

In 'CreateMediaSinkActivate' you must write something like this:

```
DWORD globalVideoIndex = 0;

HRESULT CreateMediaSinkActivate(
IMFStreamDescriptor *pSourceSD,     // Pointer to the stream descriptor.
DWORD& iStreamID, // ctream index
IMFActivate *pVideoRendererActivate,                  // Handle to the video      renderer activate.
IMFActivate **ppActivate
)
{
IMFMediaTypeHandler *pHandler = NULL;
IMFActivate *pActivate = NULL;

// Get the media type handler for the stream.
HRESULT hr = pSourceSD->GetMediaTypeHandler(&pHandler);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    goto done;
}

// Get the major media type.
GUID guidMajorType;
hr = pHandler->GetMajorType(&guidMajorType);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    goto done;
}

// Create an IMFActivate object for the renderer, based on the media type.
if (MFMediaType_Audio == guidMajorType)
{
    // Create the audio renderer.
    hr = MFCreateAudioRendererActivate(&pActivate);
}
else if (MFMediaType_Video == guidMajorType)
{
    // Share the video renderer.

    hr = pVideoRendererActivate->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARG(pActivate))

    iStreamID = globalVideoIndex++;
}
else
{
    // Unknown stream type. 
    hr = E_FAIL;
    // Optionally, you could deselect this stream instead of failing.
}
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    goto done;
}

// Return IMFActivate pointer to caller.
*ppActivate = pActivate;
(*ppActivate)->AddRef();

done:
SafeRelease(&pHandler);
SafeRelease(&pActivate);
return hr;
}
```

In `AddBranchToPartialTopology` you must write:

```
// Create the output node for the renderer.
hr = AddOutputNode(pTopology, pSinkActivate, iStreamID, &pOutputNode);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    goto done;
}
```

for Audio streams `iStreamID` will zero, but for video stream it will increment from global variable `globalVideoIndex`.

Idea is that code create `Activate` for video renderer BEFORE create `Topology` - it is OK. Then this ONE video renderer activate share by ref pointer between ALL video streams in MediaSource by checking condition `if (MFMediaType_Video == guidMajorType)`. Each VIDEO stream has got unique id from 0 by incrementing global variable `globalVideoIndex++` - this id set in method `hr = AddOutputNode(pTopology, pSinkActivate, iStreamID, &pOutputNode);`. As a result, all video streams will be drawn by ONE video renderer, and video stream with `iStreamID` is 0 will `reference background`, while other video streams will additional.

Comment: Thanks for details but It is hard to digest. I am using MediaSession and I am able to render one video stream, using example provided in the Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703190(v=vs.85).aspx  But I want to display Two video stream (no audio for now) so how can I do this?

Comment: I have wrote: create TWO MediaSource from two video file paths(URL). 4. by function MFCreateAggregateSource create from TWO MediaSource - ONE MediaSource and retuurn MediaSource from method player HRESULT CreateMediaSource(PCWSTR sURL, IMFMediaSource **ppSource);

Comment: You must create new version `CreateMediaSource` with TWO URL strings for arguments - for example `HRESULT CreateMediaSource(PCWSTR sURL1, PCWSTR sURL2, IMFMediaSource **ppSource)`. Then from original `CreateMediaSource` copy code for creating MediaSource for each URL, but DO NOT return value. Then while you will have in code TWO different MediaSources you must create object with `IMFCollection` by function [MFCreateCollection](MFCreateCollection).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137398/discussion-between-a-user-and-evgeny-pereguda).