# two video streams to one screen - media foundation

Tags: video-streaming, ms-media-foundation, mixer

The purpose is display two video streams on one screen.

I'm using the following MSDN Sample code. and stack

1. Audio/Video playback

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317914(v=vs.85).aspx

2. Creating Transform Nodes

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb250384(v=vs.85).aspx

3. Adding a Decoder to a Topology

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb250371(v=vs.85).aspx

4. stack

[Add two media sources in topology and display mix video - Windows Media Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557581/add-two-media-sources-in-topology-and-display-mix-video-windows-media-foundati?rq=1)

my media source has two video streams in one file.
and I didn't make IMFCollection through MFCreateAggregateSource.
but there is no output.

I make media two media sink. and it works. but It is display alternately without index value.

I think it is a problem that IMFTransForm::AddInputStreams, getStreamLimits... is not called.

I don't know what should i do.

Hear is the code:

```
HRESULT CreatePlaybackTopology( .... )
{
    ....
    hr = MFCreateVideoRendererActivate(hVideoWnd, &pVideoRendererActivate);
    // For each stream, create the topology nodes and add them to the topology.
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < cSourceStreams; i++)
    {
        hr = AddBranchToPartialTopology(pTopology, pSource, pPD, i, pVideoRendererActivate);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            goto done;
        }
    }
....
}
```

AddBranchPartialTopilogy method.

```
HRESULT AddBranchToPartialTopology(
IMFTopology *pTopology,         // Topology.
IMFMediaSource *pSource,        // Media source.
IMFPresentationDescriptor *pPD, // Presentation descriptor.
DWORD iStream,                  // Stream index.
IMFActivate* pVideoRendererActivate)                 // Window for video playback.
{
    IMFStreamDescriptor *pSD = NULL;
    IMFActivate         *pSinkActivate = NULL;
    IMFTopologyNode     *pSourceNode = NULL;
    IMFTopologyNode     *pOutputNode = NULL;
    IMFTopologyNode     *pDecoderNode = NULL;
    IMFTopologyNode     *pMFTNode = NULL;

    BOOL fSelected = FALSE;
CLSID clsidDecoder = GUID_NULL;

HRESULT hr = pPD->GetStreamDescriptorByIndex(iStream, &fSelected, &pSD);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    goto done;
}

DWORD iStreamID = 0;

if (fSelected)
{
    // Create the media sink activation object.
    hr = CreateMediaSinkActivate(pSD, iStreamID, pVideoRendererActivate, &pSinkActivate);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Add a source node for this stream.
    hr = AddSourceNode(pTopology, pSource, pPD, pSD, &pSourceNode);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Create the output node for the renderer.
    hr = AddOutputNode(pTopology, pSinkActivate, iStreamID, &pOutputNode);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Find a decoder.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = FindDecoderForStream(pSD, &clsidDecoder);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        if (clsidDecoder == GUID_NULL)
        {
            // No decoder is required. 
            // Connect the source node to the output node.
            hr = pSourceNode->ConnectOutput(0, pOutputNode, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            // Add a decoder node.
            hr = AddTransformNode(pTopology, clsidDecoder, &pDecoderNode);
            hr = AddTransformNode(pTopology, CLSID_TopviewMFT, &pMFTNode);
            // Connect the source node to the decoder node.
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = pSourceNode->ConnectOutput(0, pDecoderNode, 0);
            }

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = pDecoderNode->ConnectOutput(0, pMFTNode, 0);
            }

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = pMFTNode->ConnectOutput(0, pOutputNode, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
// else: If not selected, don't add the branch. 

done:
    SafeRelease(&pSD);
    SafeRelease(&pSinkActivate);
    SafeRelease(&pSourceNode);
    SafeRelease(&pOutputNode);
    SafeRelease(&pDecoderNode);
    SafeRelease(&pMFTNode);

    return hr;
}
```

CreateMediaSinkActivate methode.

```
DWORD globalVideoIndex = 0;
HRESULT CreateMediaSinkActivate(
    IMFStreamDescriptor *pSourceSD,     // Pointer to the stream descriptor.
    DWORD& iStreamID,
    IMFActivate* pVideoRendererActivate,                  // Handle to the video clipping window.
    IMFActivate **ppActivate
)
{
    IMFMediaTypeHandler *pHandler = NULL;
    IMFActivate *pActivate = NULL;

    // Get the media type handler for the stream.
    HRESULT hr = pSourceSD->GetMediaTypeHandler(&pHandler);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Get the major media type.
    GUID guidMajorType;
    hr = pHandler->GetMajorType(&guidMajorType);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Create an IMFActivate object for the renderer, based on the media type.
    if (MFMediaType_Audio == guidMajorType)
    {
        // Create the audio renderer.
        hr = MFCreateAudioRendererActivate(&pActivate);
    }
    else if (MFMediaType_Video == guidMajorType)
    {
        // Create the video renderer.
//        hr = MFCreateVideoRendererActivate(hVideoWindow, &pActivate);
    hr = pVideoRendererActivate->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pActivate));
    iStreamID = globalVideoIndex++;
    }
    else
    {
        // Unknown stream type. 
        hr = E_FAIL;
        // Optionally, you could deselect this stream instead of failing.
    }
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Return IMFActivate pointer to caller.
    *ppActivate = pActivate;
    (*ppActivate)->AddRef();

    done:
        SafeRelease(&pHandler);
        SafeRelease(&pActivate);

        return hr;
}
```

MFT .h

```
interface IMFVideoMixerControl;

class CTopview : BaseObject, 
    public IMFVideoDeviceID,
    public IMFGetService,
    public IMFTopologyServiceLookupClient,
    public IMFTransform,
//  public IMFVideoMixerControl,
    public IMFAttributes
{
public:
    static HRESULT CreateInstance(IUnknown *pUnkOuter, REFIID iid, void **ppSource);

    // IUnknown
    STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID iid, void** ppv);
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef();
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release();
....
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot clear understand the reason to include nodes `clsidDecoder` and `CLSID_TopviewMFT`? What is the purpose of `CTopview`.

Comment: In addition,  your code looks like OK, but there is one moment - I found that Microsoft Media sink from `MFCreateVideoRendererActivate` function cannot for displaying of two streams - I have spent much time, but DIDNOT found solution. So, I have another way - I have CREATED another MediaSink for Displaying video - demo program you can find by link: [NativeMediaFoundationPlayer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1017223/CaptureManager-SDK#fourtyfirstdemoprogram)

Comment: MY SOLUTION has some differences from Microsoft. Firstly, It creates list of Topology Node with Media Sinks - if you need to display two video stream - you must create list with TWO Topology Nodes. Secondly, my solution share render target between streams while Microsoft share one media sink between streams. Thirdly, my solution allows use TWO type render targets - HWND like solution from Microsoft, and DirectX9 texture - it allows integrate player in DirectX 3D - for example WPF [WPFMediaFoundationPlayer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1017223/CaptureManager-SDK#fourtyseconddemoprogram)

Comment: @EvgenyPereguda thanks for answer - clsidDecoder node is MSDN native decoder.  before adding this, It just displaying a single stream to flickered. but I added node, two streams were alternately displaying. of course, when i added two sink.  - CLSID_TopviewMFT is CTopview class. It is custom mixer for custom video effect.

Comment: @pevrizz I have successfully implemented a video mixing (render and save to file) using IMFSourceReader/IMFSinkWriter approach. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @VuVirt thanks, I have not solved this problem yet.  please let me know how you succeeded.

Comment: @pevrizz  I didn't use IMFSession/IMFtopology. I used an IMFSourceReader to read the video (and audio) samples with it asynchronously. Additionally, an IMFSinkWriter is initialized to output the samples to either EVR sink, or to MP4 sink. The video samples are processed and sent to the Sink Writer in a mixing thread.

Comment: @VuVirt It is very difficult to use the IMFSession. I'd rather use IMFSourceReader/IMFSinkWriter. thank you to reply